# Can Appium be served any Selenium Grid phone device, without specifying "udid" or "deviceName" as a DesiredCapability?

Tags: appium, selenium-grid

I want to have multiple hardware smartphones connected to Selenium Grid, as
Appium nodes (one appium server/device).  I also want to only specify the
Selenium Grid Hub as the target in my Appium tests.

If I do this, Appium seems to require that I specify a "deviceName" or "udid" as a DesiredCapability.  Specifying either of these means my test will only target a single specific device that is hard-coded into the test, instead of targeting any device that meets "platform".

How can I use Appium with Selenium Grid to just choose any device that meets DesiredCapabilities, instead of targeting a specific device with the (seemingly required) "udid" or "deviceName"?

As a use case, I have (1) iOS hardware device and (1) Android hardware device.  I would like my AppiumDriver instantiation to only have a Desired Capability of that specifies Android or IOS and just return any device that meets those capabilities.

Comment: You don't need to specify the udid with appium, you can pass this udid to driver as a capability.

Comment: Doesn't passing "udid" to the driver as a DesiredCapability restrict the test to a single machine?  This is the core of my original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try running tests from testNG.xml and keep all the deviceName in testNG.xml, I've kept a if-else block for the apk path as I had two different machines.


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Automation" parallel="tests">

        <test name="Test1">
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="XYZZZZZ" />
            <classes>
                <class name="poc.grid.GridTest" />
            </classes>
        </test>

        <test name="Test2">
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="ZYXXXXX" />
            <classes>
                <class name="poc.grid.GridTest" />
            </classes>
        </test>

    </suite>
```

**    And keep the test class like: **

```
public void appium_driver(String deviceName)
        {
            try
            {
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
                capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
                capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

                if(deviceName.equalsIgnoreCase("XYZZZZZ")){
                    capabilities.setCapability("app", "/XXXXXX/chocolate.apk");
                }else{
                    capabilities.setCapability("app", "/XXXXXX/chocolate.apk");
                }

                capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "120");
                WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://WHERE_HUB_RUNNNING_IP:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);

                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This moves the device management into a static list, within XML.  It still doesn't let Selenium Grid choose a hardware device that meets the DesiredCapabillities.  I'd like to just register the device with the Selenium Grid hub, and the test should just pick it up.

Comment: @Jerry: Even though you register appium server with flag -U <deviceID>, still you need to send deviceName capability to appium server to initialise the driver else you can not proceed with test appium test and you'll get this         error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: The following desired capabilities are required, but were not provided: deviceName
info: [debug] Error: The following desired capabilities are required, but were not provided: deviceName    ==> To avoid this deviceName can be passed through xml and utilised in tests. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also had issues with the udid capability. To me (as a appium beginner) it's just not clear enough which capability you can send to match and which one you can send to overwrite a setting. I know the defaultcapabilitymatcher only matches a few:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/internal/utils/DefaultCapabilityMatcher.java

However I needed to add the udid to the session creation to make it work for me in my setting. So maybe my findings are usefull for you as well. [How to make sure the appium node is connected to only one phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017543/how-to-make-sure-the-appium-node-is-connected-to-only-one-phone)